# Hover on <a href only works after a click or page refresh

Tags: html, css, hover

I have a problem with my site. 
I'm using HTML and CSS only.
I'm using several "a hrefs" that are supposed to slightly change their background colors when hovered.
The problem is, whenever I clear the browser's cache (or go into inprivate mode) I need to refresh the webpage or click on a link, which ONLY then (all of them) starts to do the hovering effect. Only by clicking a second time I'm able to open that link.
This happens in all browsers.
I have the following code on the head section.

```
<link href="css/sticky-menu.css?v=2.4" rel="stylesheet">
```

Anyone suspects what is happening here?

Comment: your question is not clear can you elaborate it more or share me the codepen link

Comment: I guess on codepen it's working fine: https://codepen.io/lsdigitall/pen/GRoJPBJ Maybe I should start from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem, and it's related to a third-party script, in this case from sharethis.com
I guess I'm going to contact them about this.
Thanks, anyway.